# Android + Arduino bluetooth communication

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I have a question about android bluetooth working principle. I have an app that connects to arduino with HC-06 shield. And on receive i get new line after first char. Lets say i send from arduino

`12345`

and in android i see in ListView

`1
2345`

I believe this is about android not arduino, because i connected arduino to PC and i received correct data.

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
// construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
break;
```

Any ideas how to debug is it really android or maybe its arduino failing?
If you are interested i post arduino code:

```
void loop() // run over and over
{
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
  if (Serial.available())
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
```

**EDIT**
The problem about "\n" comes out only with arduino+HC-06 bluetooth shield. While connected to pc the android tablet shows correct data.

Comment: Why don't you use a BufferedReader and readLine()??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to check string ending.

```
private void onBluetoothRead(byte[] buffer, int len) {

        String output = new String(buffer, 0, len); // Add read buffer to new string
        Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, String.format("Received: "+ output + " , " + "%d bytes", len));
        outputTemp += output;
        if (outputTemp.endsWith("\n")){
        m_deviceOutput.append(outputTemp); // Add (not replace) string to TextView
        StringTokenizer  splitStr = new StringTokenizer(outputTemp, ","); // split string by comma
        String numberOne = splitStr.nextToken().replaceAll("\\D+",""); // First split string
        String numberTwo = splitStr.nextToken().replaceAll("\\D+",""); // Second split string
        m_deviceOutputPrs.setText(numberOne);
        m_deviceOutputSpeed.setText(numberTwo);
        outputTemp = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need more time to receive the whole message. You may either append data to the same buffer, not the new one; or you may add a small delay between the time you detected new input data and the time you read the whole input data.

Comment: kirill how you suggest to do the delay? And how to append data to same buffer? Be more specific :) i am not an expert in java...